# Nginx exclude substring from a string

Tags: regex, string, nginx

I am looking for a to exclude a substring from a string with nginx regex :

exclude a substring : toto
I try many example from internet, but I don't find the correct one.

Not matching :

```
toto.example.instance.fr
titi-toto.example.instance.fr
```

Matching :

```
titi.example.instance.fr
titi-titi.example.instance.fr
```

I try this regex :

```
^((?!toto).)\.example\.instance\.fr$
```

but when I add example.instance.fr, it is matching nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^((?!toto).)` part of your regex matches any single character (`.`) at the start of the string (`^`), that does not start a `toto` char sequence. However, `toto` cannot be matched even without the lookahead, since after the `.` part, `\.example\.instance\.fr$` comes and definitely requires `.example.instance.fr` to appear right after that single char matched with `.`.

You can use

```
^(?![^.]*toto\.)[^.]+\.example\.instance\.fr$
```

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![^.]*toto\.)` - no zero or more chars other than `.` followed with `toto.` string allowed at the start
- `[^.]+` - one or more chars other than `.`
- `\.example\.instance\.fr$` - `.example.instance.fr` string till end of the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MN6M2h/1).

**Note**

If `toto` must be matched as a whole word, you can add a word boundary:

```
^(?![^.]*\btoto\.)[^.]+\.example\.instance\.fr$
         ^^
```